# JQM layout does not work with IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile, html5shiv

I am developing a mobile website with JQM, but I dont seem to get it work with IE9. Layout is so different with other browsers and all elements are messed up. I am using the html5shiv, but I dont think thats the case here.

Here is what I am using:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
```

And then just basic divs in HTML-markup.

URL: http://paaluttaja.elasticbeanstalk.com

I hope someone can point me to the right direction... I dont need a full solution.

Comment: Your going to need to be a bit more specific, for example what "does not work". Aside from that it's better to post your markup/code instead of just a link to your website.

Comment: I added some more info, but its hard to paste all source code here, because I dont know where to start looking the fault.

Comment: Just to play devils advocate. This is almost a non-issue. JQM is for mobile devices (Android, Windows Phone, iOS) to really you don't need it to work in IE9.

Comment: @Swordfish0321 yes and no. jQM clearly targets mobile but it is also tested on and works fine with all the major desktop browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am missing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

from beginning of the file, it solves my issues. IE seems to be only browsers who demands it to be present.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is missing the required layout. You have `<div data-role="page">` blocks but are missing the required content block;

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
     </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        my content here
    </div>
</div>
```